# Netcore 3.1 UTF8JSON Serializer adding literal Key and Value to result

Tags: c#, dapper, utf8json

Netcore 3.1 UTF8JSON Serializer adding literal Key and Value to dapper query result.

```cs
public async Task<List<dynamic>> JsonQs(string sql, object param = null, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
{
    using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    IEnumerable<dynamic> data = await conn.QueryAsync(sql, param, commandType: commandType);
    return data.ToList();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> GetRecord([FromQuery] ReportFilter model)
{
    var res = await _repo.JsonQs("GetBreakdown", model);
    return Ok(res);
}
```

Output:

```json
[[{"Key":"Id","Value":"INV1"},{"Key":"Id","Value":"INV2"} ]]
```

Expected output:

```json
[{"Id":"INV 1"},{"Id":"INV2"}]
```

Comment: Probably stop using `dynamic` and dealing with regular types would help. There's no reason for `dynamic`.

Comment: `UTF8JSON Serializer` do you mean `System.Text.Json`?

Answer (score 2):

`data.ToList()` returns a list of [KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=net-5.0) list, either because `await conn.QueryAsync(sql, param, commandType: commandType);` returns a [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0) or `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-5.0) Interface.

You need to map the result from `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` using: `Select(i => new { Id = i.Value })`

```
public async Task<List<dynamic>> JsonQs(string sql, object param = null, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
{
    using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    IEnumerable<dynamic> data = await conn.QueryAsync(sql, param, commandType: commandType);
    return data.Select(i => new { Id = i.Value }).ToList();
}
    
public async Task<IActionResult> GetRecord([FromQuery] ReportFilter model)
{
    var res = await _repo.JsonQs("GetBreakdown", model);
    return Ok(res);
}
```

Comment: even without return data.ToList(); If i do return data; I still get same result

Comment: I have edited the answer to include full code.  you must include: `return data.Select(i => new { Id = i.Value }).ToList();`

Comment: result is [{},{},{},{},{}]....empty objects with correct counts.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved.
The solution is UTF8JSON doesn't play nicely with dynamic.
Changed the type to a class/POCO and it's all solved.

```
public async Task<List<User>> JsonQs(string sql, object param = null, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
{
    using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    IEnumerable<User> data = await conn.QueryAsync(sql, param, commandType: commandType);
    return data;
}
```